# Java Canvas irregular drawing time?

Tags: java, performance, swing, canvas, awt

I have a `Canvas` from the `java.awt` package added to a `JFrame`. The `Canvas` uses Double-Buffering to draw, enabled with `canvas.createBufferStrategy(2)`.

That's my `render()` method, which should be quite fast, because I'm not drawing so much:

```
Graphics g = strategy.getDrawGraphics();

// draw
g.drawImage(...); // Image with a size of 1000x1000
g.drawString(...); // Drawing a short String with the Frames per Second
drawModel(g); // this method draws a rotated game character with the 
              // help of Gaphics2D (Imagesize: 100x100)

g.dispose();
strategy.show();
```

I've measured the Performance with the help of System.currentTimeMillis() and I got that results (Time per Frame):

- 9ms
- 9ms
- 11ms
- 10ms
- 0ms
- 21ms
- 10ms

How can it happen that one render process takes 0ms and the next the double of the average time? And what are your suggestions to improve the overall rendering performance?

**// UPDATE**

I've tried a `JPanel` now: it's flaring and it's much slower than a Canvas.

Comment: 1)  Don't mix Swing & AWT components.  Use a `JPanel` or `BufferedImage` as a drawing surface.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What's your platform's clock resolution?

Comment: @AndrewThompson is a JPanel really a good Component for drawing with a Graphics object? (i think it doesn't support double-buffering)

Comment: `JPanel` is double buffered by default.  See [Double Buffering and Page Flipping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html) for details.

Comment: I've a Intel i7 third generation... How can I check my clock resolution?
@AndrewThompson So I can draw directly with the Graphics from paintComponent(Graphics g)?

Comment: *"Intel i7 third generation"*  Excellent.  But what is the clock resolution?

Comment: @AndrewThompson How can I check it? (Win7)

Comment: First of all, you'd have to post the code with which you measured the timings. Secondly, regarding your various statements about `JPanel` drawing being slower, again, the question is how you do it, and also it's really unlikely that it flickers if you use it correctly. So there's a very high chance that your approach is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is often no more accurate than 10 ms. Try `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: I've changed it and it is more accurate, but rounded on one millisecond it is in my case mostly the same as `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Anyway, thank you I'll use `System.nanoTime()` from now on.

Comment: @LeeheLee "rounded on one millisecond it is in my case mostly the same as System.currentTimeMillis()" That's odd. In the past I've found System.nanoTime to be far more accurate. Watch out for thread switches, unnecessary memory allocation (and corresponding garbage collection), and unpredictable things like that.